# BlueImp file upload plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, blueimp

I have a page that has the following input elemet:

```html
<input class="uploadDocument" type="file" name="FileData" id="my-upl" />
```

And then the following javascript for starting the upload:

```js
$("#my-upl").fileupload({
  url: uploadUrl,
  dataType: 'string',
  done: successFunction,
  uploadProgress: function(e, data) {
    var pct = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
    updateProgressBar(progressDiv, progressBar, progressLabel, Math.round(pct));
  },
  fail: function(e, data) {
    var errorHtml = uploadFailedHtml + "<p>" + data.textStatus + "</p>";
    showModal(uploadFailedTitle, errorHtml);
  }
});
```

It seems that the file upload does not trigger. I've even tried specifying a "start" and an "always" callback to see if anything gets triggered but to no avail.

**EDIT:** I've added an "add" callback and this does get triggered when the file is selected but the upload does not start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was found by looking at what code is run when [using a button to start the upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin#how-to-start-uploads-with-a-button-click)

In my add callback, I simply had to do `data.submit()`:

```js
$("#my-upl").fileupload({
  url: uploadUrl,
  dataType: 'string',
  done: successFunction,
  uploadProgress: function(e, data) {
    var pct = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
    updateProgressBar(progressDiv, progressBar, progressLabel, Math.round(pct));
  },
  fail: function(e, data) {
    var errorHtml = uploadFailedHtml + "<p>" + data.textStatus + "</p>";
    showModal(uploadFailedTitle, errorHtml);
  },
  add: function(e, data) {
    data.submit();
    return true;
  }
});
```